# Symmetric private key generation using ESAPI API TPM

Tags: encryption, configuration, environment-variables, c, tpm

I was going through the ESAPI APIs , I have hosted the TPM simulator on my Ubuntu 22.04 desktop and trying to generate the symmetric private key from one C program and another C program using the same key for encryption and decryption simple plain text.

So far I went through this example <https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tss/blob/master/test/integration/esys-rsa-encrypt-decrypt.int.c>

And I did small compilation using -ltss2-esys the Development environment looks fine.

The generated private key where it will be stored?

```
/* Alternative for simulator */
// char *name = "mssim:host=127.0.0.1,port=2321";
```

where I can view the key I have simulator , no Hardware TPM usage as if now.

Open for any FAPI suggestions also, yet I am in Learning phase.

small console output

```
amp@amp-virtual-machine:~$ openssl rand -engine tpm2tss -hex 10
engine "tpm2tss" set.
8d76bc5c449c894a019b
```

amp@amp-virtual-machine:~$ sudo -u tss G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all tpm2-abrmd
[sudo] password for amp:
** INFO: 06:35:41.119: tabrmd startup

** (process:6838): WARNING **: 06:35:41.121: tcti_conf before: "device:/dev/tpm0"
** INFO: 06:35:41.121: logging to stdout

** (tpm2-abrmd:6838): WARNING **: 06:35:41.121: tcti_conf after: "device:/dev/tpm0"
** INFO: 06:35:41.122: entering g_main_loop
** INFO: 06:35:41.124: init_thread_func start
** (tpm2-abrmd:6838): DEBUG: 06:35:41.127: random_class_init
** (tpm2-abrmd:6838): DEBUG: 06:35:41.127: opening entropy source: /dev/urandom
** (tpm2-abrmd:6838): DEBUG: 06:35:41.127: reading from entropy source: /dev/urandom
** (tpm2-abrmd:6838): DEBUG: 06:35:41.129: connection_manager_set_property
** (tpm2-abrmd:6838): DEBUG: 06:35:41.129:   max_connections: 27
** (tpm2-abrmd:6838): DEBUG: 06:35:41.131: IpcFrontendDbus set bus_name: com.intel.tss2.Tabrmd
** (tpm2-abrmd:6838): DEBUG: 06:35:41.132: ipc_frontend_connect
ERROR:tcti:src/tss2-tcti/tcti-device.c:451:Tss2_Tcti_Device_Init() Failed to open specified TCTI device file /dev/tpm0: No such file or directory
ERROR:tcti:src/tss2-tcti/tctildr-dl.c:169:tcti_from_file() Could not initialize TCTI file: device
ERROR:tcti:src/tss2-tcti/tctildr.c:430:Tss2_TctiLdr_Initialize_Ex() Failed to instantiate TCTI

** (tpm2-abrmd:6838): CRITICAL **: 06:35:41.182: init_thread_func: failed to create TCTI with conf "device:/dev/tpm0", got RC: 0xa000a
** (tpm2-abrmd:6838): DEBUG: 06:35:41.182: init_thread_func: calling gmain_data_cleanup
** (tpm2-abrmd:6838): DEBUG: 06:35:41.186: gmain_data_cleanup
** (tpm2-abrmd:6838): DEBUG: 06:35:41.187: ipc_frontend_disconnect

(tpm2-abrmd:6838): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 06:35:41.188: g_bus_unown_name: assertion 'owner_id > 0' failed
** (tpm2-abrmd:6838): DEBUG: 06:35:41.207: random_finalize
** INFO: 06:35:41.208: main_loop_quit
** INFO: 06:35:41.219: g_main_loop_run done, cleaning up
** (tpm2-abrmd:6838): DEBUG: 06:35:41.221: gmain_data_cleanup
** INFO: 06:35:41.222: main_loop_quit
amp@amp-virtual-machine:~$ tpm2_startup -c
amp@amp-virtual-machine:~$ file /dev/urandom
/dev/urandom: character special (1/9)

Comment: Please be precise with details (*they matter!*).  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS came out in 2022-April; Ubuntu Core 22 came out in 2022-July but 22 is a *headless* server system, and Ubuntu 22.10 came out in 2022-October.   22.04 & 22.10 are desktop/server systems, 22 is server only intended for cloud/appliances...

Answer (score 0):

The steps I have figured out and received some suggestions from TPM forum, is to generate the key using openssl libs (c program) and then use FAPI APIs seal option to store key and then unseal it and use it for further cryptography steps.